# What are the "Ira" flowers?

Tags: puranas, identification-request, prayer

Verses [693](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-nilamata-purana/d/doc81740.html)-[704](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-nilamata-purana/d/doc81741.html) of the [Nilamata Purana:](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-nilamata-purana)

> A nymph named **Ira**, employed by Visvavasu, was formerly cursed by Sakra (and) was exiled from the assembly of the gods.
>
> She attained the state of being a plant in the Himavat, the best of the mountains. After Nikumbha's exit, her body breaks up into various forms.
>
> When the goddess **Ira** is adorned with **Ira flowers,** the wise man - well dressed, well-anointed, good-minded and well-concentrated should go to Ira-garden, accompanied by **Ira** wife and host of sons, and should worship the goddess his with other flowers.
>
> (He) should offer various sorts of eatables and nourishments along with earthen lamps. Special meals should be taken after going to **Ira-garden.**
>
> Then, the Brahmanas, the wife, the friends and the relatives should be honoured with **Ira-flowers. Ira-flowers** should be stitched together with a red thread.
>
> Those (stitched flowers) should be worn by one's own self and specially offered to the ladies. Vocal and instrumental music should be listened to, and dance-performances should be seen.
>
> Special drink containing **Ira-flowers** should be taken. **Ira (flowers)** should be presented to the gods. The gods are pleased in that way.
>
> With him who well-concentrated offers one thousand **Ira (flowers)** to Kesava, the lord of the gods is pleased and he goes to heaven.
>
> Rudra, Brahma, the Moon, the Sun, Subha Karisini and Durga should be worshipped with Ira (flowers). All the gods are pleased (with the offerings of **Ira flowers)**
>
> **Ira** is favourite of the Nagas and especially mine.
>
> I am excessively pleased with him who worships me with **Ira flowers** in **Ira-garden.**

But what is the *Ira* flower? What is the common name or Latin name? The name/word *[Ira](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/ira)* seems to be common and prevalent, but I can't find any explanation of what the flowers actually are. I can't think of any flowers with that name in either Hindi or Tamil, and the only helpful information the passage gives us is that these flowers grow in the Himalayas. So, what are these flowers, what do they look like, and what are they called?